# The "Object" object in node console vs in web console

Tags: javascript, node.js, console, prototype

I am relatively new to JavaScript and still trying to get my head around the prototypal inheritance. while trying to understand it I tried getting prototype property of **`Object`** object using `Object.prototype` in web console as well as in nodejs console. In web console it shows that the prototype property of **Object** object has an object with few members while in node the Object.prototype has an empty object. So my question  is "is the **Object** object in node (console) different than the one in the web console because the are different javascript engines??"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you ask for Object.prototype in node console, it will simply show an empty object. This is merely a representation of the base object. It still contains all the functions and properties you would expect and that show up in the browser console.

If you don't believe me, you can verify it yourself. Try typing `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Object)` or `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Object.prototype)` in your node console.

Answer (score 0):

No, [`Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) is the same in all implementations, the difference is just from the ways of representing it in the console.

Comment: does that mean the "Object" is created( or constructed) differently in node console ??

Comment: No, absolutely not